# Microsoft file sync Delete fies in source folder is not syncing with destination folder

Tags: c#, file, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm new to Sync Framework and I think I'm missing something important and rudimentary here.

I have a source folder and destination folder on the network. I'm trying to sync these two folders only one way, source → destination.

Everything works well, except that when I delete some files in the source folder, on the next sync I expect those files to be deleted in the destination, but that doesn't happen.

My code snippet:

```
private  void SyncronizeFolders(string source, string destination)
{
    FileSyncOptions options = FileSyncOptions.ExplicitDetectChanges |
                             FileSyncOptions.RecycleDeletedFiles | FileSyncOptions.RecyclePreviousFileOnUpdates |
                             FileSyncOptions.RecycleConflictLoserFiles;
    FileSyncScopeFilter filter = new FileSyncScopeFilter();
    filter.FileNameExcludes.Add("*.metadata");

    // Create file system provider
    FileSyncProvider sourceprovider = new FileSyncProvider(Guid.NewGuid(), _sourcefolder, filter, options);
    FileSyncProvider destinationprovider = new FileSyncProvider(Guid.NewGuid(), _destinationfolder, filter, options);

    sourceprovider.Configuration.ConflictResolutionPolicy = ConflictResolutionPolicy.SourceWins;
    destinationprovider.Configuration.ConflictResolutionPolicy = ConflictResolutionPolicy.SourceWins;

    // Ask providers to detect changes
    sourceprovider.DetectChanges();
    destinationprovider.DetectChanges();

    // Synchronization of 2 Folders
    SyncOrchestrator agent = new SyncOrchestrator();
    agent.LocalProvider = sourceprovider;
    agent.RemoteProvider = destinationprovider;
    agent.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload;
    agent.Synchronize();
}
```

Comment: Always include a tag for the primary language (without the version), or your question won't come to the attention of most people who answer questions for that language.

Comment: Sure. I'll from next time. This is the first time i"m posting on this site. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think you need to remove that line >> filter.FileNameExcludes.Add("*.metadata");
and it will be sync in all case.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `Guid.NewGuid()` for every call - this GUID is stored in the metadata that the sync framework uses to store its knowledge about the source and destination files. If you provide a new GUID each time then it can't use the previously gathered metadata.

Replace the `Guid.NewGuid()` with two fixed GUIDs (one for the source, one for the destination) and it'll start working correctly.

It's also unnecessary to exclude `*.metadata` as this is one of the built in exclusions that the framework has, as per [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902846(v=sql.110).aspx).